# Drupal Page (hook_preprocess_page ) is loading twice only on browser open not in tab

Tags: javascript, php, drupal

hook_preprocess_page is initating twice. But this occurs only when we close the browser and open it. But when we open the same page in new tab. It doesn't initating twice.

In hook_preprocess_page, when I used debug_backtrace, it shows the menu_executive_active_handler initiates it.

Why does it reloads the page twice ? When I comment the scripts in html.tpl.php. It is not reloading.

Kindly share your thoughts to debug it.

Comment: Weird.. drupal version ? Is this happening with all browsers ? which scripts are you talking about ? Please post the menu item definition and the page callback corresponding to that page url.

Comment: It looks like it's loading, page redirects, then it only loads once?